# Expo cli to bare react native cli (expo prebuild)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, eas, create-react-native-app

when i run the command npx expo prebuild the it ejects and android folder is created but metro.config file is not created.

when i try to run npx react-native start its given an error
**error No Metro config found in C:\Users\KK\Desktop\FrontendTabletApp\TestExpoProject.**
and when i run npx react-native run-android ,the JS server starts and closes immediately and when the emulator starts it gives an error for Js server is not connected.

and this is my package.json simple newly created project of expo converted to bare react native cli

````
{
  "name": "testexpoproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}```
````